# Is there a difference between using upstream and fastcgi_pass?

Tags: nginx

Is there any difference between doing this:

```
upstream hhvm {
    server unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock;
}
...
location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_pass hhvm;
}
```

and this:

```
location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/hhvm/hhvm.sock;
}
```

Which is preferable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `upstream` allows you to do some [simple load balancing](http://nginx.org/r/upstream) between multiple backends. If you have only one backend (as seems to be the case) then it doesn't really buy you anything.

Comment: Also if you use this upstream in several places you could modify it in one place